# Strongly typed ids in F#?

Tags: f#

I have two kinds of entity in my application: customers and products. They are each identified at a database level by a UUID.

In my F# code, this can be represented by `System.Guid`.

For readability, I added some types like this:

```
open System

type CustomerId = Guid

type ProductId = Guid
```

However, this does not prevent me from using a `ProductId` as a `CustomerId` and vice-versa.

I came up with a wrapper idea to prevent this:

```
open System

[<Struct>]
type ProductId = 
  {
    Product : Guid
  }

[<Struct>]
type CustomerId = 
  {
    Customer : Guid
  }
```

This makes initialization a little more verbose, and perhaps less intuitive:

```
let productId = { Product = Guid.NewGuid () }
```

But it adds type-safety:

```
// let customerId : CustomerId = productId // Type error
```

I was wondering what other approaches there are.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [single-case union](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/) types:

```
open System

[<Struct>]
type ProductId = ProductId of Guid

[<Struct>]
type CustomerId = CustomerId of Guid

let productId = ProductId (Guid.NewGuid())
```

Normally we add some convenient helper methods/properties directly to the types:

```
[<Struct>]
type ProductId = private ProductId of Guid with
    static member Create () = ProductId (Guid.NewGuid())
    member this.Value = let (ProductId i) = this in i

[<Struct>]
type CustomerId = private CustomerId of Guid with
    static member Create () = CustomerId (Guid.NewGuid())
    member this.Value = let (CustomerId i) = this in i

let productId = ProductId.Create ()
productId.Value |> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 8):

Another approach, which is less common, but worth mentioning is to use so-called *phantom types*. The idea is that you will have a generic wrapper `ID<'T>` and then use different types for `'T` to represent different types of IDs. Those types are never actually instantiated, which is why they're called *phantom* types.

```
[<Struct>]
type ID<'T> = ID of System.Guid

type CustomerID = interface end
type ProductID = interface end
```

Now you can create `ID<CustomerID>` and `ID<ProductID>` values to represent two kinds of IDs:

```
let newCustomerID () : ID<CustomerID> = ID(System.Guid.NewGuid())
let newProductID () : ID<ProductID> = ID(System.Guid.NewGuid())
```

The nice thing about this is that you can write functions that work with any ID easily:

```
let printID (ID g) = printfn "%s" (g.ToString())
```

For example, I can now create one customer ID, one product ID and print both, but I cannot do equality test on those IDs, because they're types do not match:

```
let ci = newCustomerID ()
let pi = newProductID ()
printID ci
printID pi
ci = pi // Type mismatch. Expecting a 'ID<CustomerID>' but given a 'ID<ProductID>'
```

This is a neat trick, but it is a bit more complicated than just using new type for each ID. In particular, you will likely need more type annotations in various places to make this work and the type errors might be less clear, especially when there is generic code involved. However, it's worth mentioning this as an alternative.

Comment: This is very interesting. Single-case unions are already quite cumbersome to work with imho, so it's nice to explore options.

Comment: Do you have to use a phantom type here though? Let's say you want it to be an ID for your existing type `type Person = {Name: string; Age: int}`, can't you just say `let fetchPerson (id:ID<Person>) : async<Person> = .......` ?

Comment: I made one: ```type ID<'A, 'B> =
    | ID of 'B
    static member nw b = ID b
    member this.Value = match this with ID id -> id```, so you can chose between string, GUID or int64, and then make aliases like so: ```type PersonId = ID<Person, string>
and Person =
    { Id: PersonId
      Name: string } // etc.```

Comment: This is nice if and only if you want all IDs in your system to be of the same type. This is IMO a smell. I don't know what type any third party id might be, and a CountryId, for instance, I'd hope uses the formal ISO standard. I do (often) see the value above, but one has to have this problem in mind, in my opinion.